# Programación Dinámica (Error en Recurrencia)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursión

Tengo un inconveniente con una recurrencia en python.
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    from sys import stdin
#import sys
#sys.setrecursionlimit(500000)
def graph(i,j):
    global n,matriz
    #print(matriz[i-1][j])
    if i==n: return matriz[n-1][1]
    elif j==0:return min(matriz[i][j]+graph(i,j+1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j+1))
    elif j==1:return min(matriz[i][j]+graph(i,j+1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j-1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j+1))
    elif j==2:return min(matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j),matriz[i][j]+graph(i,j-1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j-1))
def main():
    global n,matriz
    n=int(stdin.readline())
    matriz=[]
    for k in range(n):
        matriz.append([int(x) for x in stdin.readline().split()])
    #print(matriz)
    (graph(0,1))
    print(matriz)
main()
```

Al ejecutarlo me marca este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call least):

  File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Tri graphs.py", line 9, in graph
    elif j==1:return min(matriz[i][j]+graph(i,j+1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j-1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j+1))
  File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Tri graphs.py", line 10, in graph
    elif j==2:return min(matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j),matriz[i][j]+graph(i,j-1),matriz[i][j]+graph(i+1,j-1))
```

y varias lineas mas...

Alguien sabe que significa dicho error???
Gracias!

Comment: David agrega la traza completa del error por favor, te faltan las líneas finales que son las que indican la excepción precisamente (aunque probablemente sea un error de indexación. es posible que estes intentando usar un índice que no existe en la matriz ). Por otro lado, aumentar el límite de recursión puede ser peligroso (aunque el límite en Python es bastante conservador). Rara vez un algoritmo recursivo no se puede hacer de forma iterativa (en muchos casos es incluso más eficiente y legible), sería bueno que explicaras que pretendes conseguir con tu código. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola!, La idea del programa es de un problema llamado  Tri Graphs, un problema de la plataforma UVA Online Judge, hace una matriz y busca la menor suma, bueno no se como explicarlo muy bien.....y este error queda como un bucle infinito se repite indefinidamente por lo que solo la parte debajo del Traceback (most recent call least): es la que se repite muchas veces..... Espero haberme hecho entender

Comment: Vale, si he entendido lo que es se trata de un problema clásico de grafos; dado un tri-grafo, es decir un grafo acíclico (no se puede ir a la fila superior ni al vértice situado a la izquierda) de 3 columnas y n filas buscar el camíno menos costoso (el coste lo dan los vértices) entre el vértice superior e inferior de la segunda columna. ¿Es esto? Si es así el problema creo que es que superas el límite de recursión. Tiene fácil solución con programación dinámica en una algoritmo iterativo mucho más simple que usando recursión. ¿Puedes confirmar si este es el problema o colocar el enunciado?

Comment: SI este es el problema, según lo  que dices es mejor hacerlo iterativo??